# FPU version for Cortex-M microcontrollers

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m, fpu

From a simple google search, I found out that the fpu version for Tiva C Launchpad is fpv4-sp-d16 but which document tells the fpu version of various microcontrollers(tm4c123gh6pm, stm32f407, stm32f446re, etc.)?

arm-none-eabi-gcc --print-multi-lib

gives the information about architecture and abi but fpu version is not mentioned for a particular architectute.

Comment: there is a whole chapter in the arm architectural reference manual...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arm community suggested the following answer

"ARM Cortex‑M4 Processor Technical Reference Manual" gives this information

[ARM Cortex-M4 TRM](https://developer.arm.com/docs/100166/0001?_ga=2.7521777.2107193367.1556507946-1242998727.1556505017)

Section 7.1 about fpu says "The Cortex-M4 FPU is an implementation of the single precision variant of the ARMv7-M Floating Point Extension(FPv4-SP)"

Also the 32 single precision registers can be combined into 16 double precision ones (d16) hence fpv4-sp-d16

Answer (score 4):

The FPU is defined by ARM, hence you need to look at the ARM core definitions. Note that FPU is optional for the cores, so you do need to check the silicon vendors' doc on whether they include the FPU or not.

For Cortex-M4, the optional FPU is 32-bits, i.e. single precision FP. Note that this means that double precision (i.e. 64-bit FP) is done without using the FPU.

Cortex-M7 definition includes an optional 64-bit FPU and can execute both single and double precision FP instructions.

Orthogonal to the FPU used is the *calling convention* that your program uses. As related to FP. basically it means whether to pass function arguments in FP registers on normal ARM registers.